# find $T(x,y,z)$ given the eigenvalues and eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, solution-verification

I have to find $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (which is linear) given the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=3$ with eigenspaces
$$V(1)=\{(x,x+y,y); x,y \in \mathbb{R}\} \equiv [(1,1,0),(0,1,1)] $$
$$V(3)=\{(0,x,2x); x \in \mathbb{R}\} \equiv [(0,1,2)]$$

My approach was to consider the basis $\beta=\{(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,2)\}$ and by the equation $T(v)=\lambda{v}$, where $v$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ (right?). Thus:
$$T(1,1,0)=\lambda_1(1,1,0)=(1,1,0)\\
T(0,1,1)=\lambda_1(0,1,1)=(0,1,1)\\
T(0,1,2)=\lambda_3(0,1,2)=(0,3,6)$$
writting $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of the elements of $\beta$:
$$(x,y,z)=(\alpha_1,\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3,\alpha_2+2\alpha_3)$$
it's easy to show that $\alpha_1=x,\;\;\alpha_2=2y-2x-z,\;\;\alpha_3=z+x-y$. Plugging them in the equation above and applying T (which is linear) I got
$$T(x,y,z)=(x,2x+2z-y,4x-4y+5z)$$
I've checked that this transformation has eigenvalues 1 and 3 (it's good!). and the eigenspaces for these eigenvectors are generated by the same vectors ($[(1,1,0),(0,1,1)]$ for $\lambda=1$ and $[(0,1,2)]$ for $\lambda=3$). It seems to be consistent to me, but I wanna know if I made some mistake during my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work looks correct.  In matrices, you could see this as converting to coordinates in the eigenvector basis, in which the transformation matrix is diagonal, and back again to standard coordinates, as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 \\ 1&1&1 \\ 0&1&2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
1&1&1 \\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
2&-1&2 \\
4&-4&5
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Great! btw the second part of the question is asking if T is diagonalizable. I believe it follows directly from you answer, right?

Comment: Yes, you can see it being diagonalized in my answer